# how to build Slick-carousel

Tags: makefile, slick.js

I'm trying to build a fork of [slick-carousel](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) by Ken Wheeler.

The project is quite old and that implies it has a different build setup than most projects we can see lately.

Files relevant for the build (you can look for more on the Github linked above)

`Makefile`:

```
build: components slick.js slick.css
    @component build --dev

components: component.json
    @component install --dev

.PHONY: clean
```

`component.json`:

```
{
    "name": "slick",
    "repo": "kenwheeler/slick",
    "description": "the last carousel you'll ever need",
    "version": "1.8.1",
    "keywords": ["ui", "jquery", "carousel", "responsive", "slider"],
    "dependencies": {
        "component/jquery": "*"
    },
    "development": {},
    "scripts": {
        "slick/slick.js": "slick.js"
    },
    "styles": {
        "slick/slick.css": "slick.css",
        "slick/slick-theme.css": "slick-theme.css"
    }
}
```

So far I was able to figure out I needed the [componentjs](https://github.com/componentjs) build tool.

**Note:** current version is `1.x` but slick's component.json syntax only works with version `0.x`.

```
npm install -g component@0
```

Then I try to run `make` to build:

- I get an output in the /components directory
- Then I get an error:

> make: *** No rule to make target `slick.js', needed by `build'.  Stop.

I'm not sure what that means, I've read I could have a make version incompatible with the one used to build the lib originally; but I don't see any meta that could help me find a proper make version to use.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Makefile and componentjs are not used now.

You can develop slick by opening index.html with browser. Just drag it to browser tab or open `file:///path/to/slick/index.html` with browser.

I assume if you want to constibute to js file, all you need to do is just edit `slick/slick.js` and minify it as `slick/slick.min.js`. Then make a pull-request.
Because the slick.js is UMD style out of the box, thus only need to do is to minify.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `slick.js` is in the same directory. Note also that `Slick.js` is not equal to `slick.js`(case sensitive).

Also, I found this thread on trying to build a fork with a similar error. Although it is about a different project, it may help. Have a look: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/28987

Here is an another piece of information that *might* help:

> You can't run make config just anywhere - You have to be in a directory which >contains a Make file. To verify:
>
> ```
> ls Makefile
> ```
>
> This file has to contain a target called `config`:
>
> ```
> grep ^config Makefile
> ```
>
> (this last command will not match all possible Makefile syntax, but if it's a >simple file it should at least show you if there is another target like >`configure` or `configuration`.)
>
> (You should look at the original post at this adress:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103080/how-do-i-fix-make-no-rule-to-make-target-config)